# watch a file for modification and get the content to be added

Tags: java

I know WatchService in Java7 but I need the added content that was inserted to the file. How can I do that?

For example: I have a log file that I want to watch and check the log entries that were added to the file.

Also is there any way to carry on the watch if the program exited (e.g. JVM crashed)? storing a file pointer or similar?

Thank you very much for your help!
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should be able to satisfy your requirements. Although it's a bit lengthy and might need some refactoring, it should work out of the box. I embedded my comments between the lines and can explain further if necessary.

You only need to create '/tmp/log.txt' file, execute the code and add some content to the file. The content will appear on the Java console once the file is saved.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FileWatcher {

    private static final String POINTER_FILE_PATH = "/tmp/pointer.txt";

    private static final String LOG_FILE_PATH = "/tmp/log.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        File logFile = new File(LOG_FILE_PATH);

        //read the previous position in the log file
        long pointer = getLastPointer();

        while (true) {
            long fsize = logFile.length();

            // calculate the length of new content from the pointer position
            int length = (int) (fsize - pointer);

            if (length == 0) {
                // save CPU cycles if nothing happened in the log file
                Thread.sleep(100);
                continue;
            }

            if (fsize < pointer) {
                // throw exception if any file content has been deleted
                // (doesn't cater for caracter replacement)
                throw new RuntimeException("Tampered file content");
            }

            // initialise a new buffer for the new content
            byte[] buf = new byte[length];

            int actualLength = readFileContent(pointer, buf, length);

            // increment the position of the pointer in the file
            pointer = pointer + actualLength;

            //save the current pointer
            storePointer(pointer);

            // print out the new content
            System.out.print(new String(buf, 0, actualLength));
        }

    }

    private static int readFileContent(long pointer, byte[] buf, int length) throws IOException {
        // open a new input stream to the log file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(LOG_FILE_PATH);

        try {
            // skip to the previous position in the log file
            fis.skip(pointer);

            // read file content into the buffer and retrieve the actual
            // number of bytes
            int actualLength = fis.read(buf, 0, length);
            return actualLength;
        } finally {
            fis.close();
        }
    }

    private static void storePointer(long pointer) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(POINTER_FILE_PATH);
            pw.write(String.valueOf(pointer));
            pw.flush();
        } finally {
            if (pw != null) {
                pw.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static long getLastPointer() throws IOException {
        long pointer = 0;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(POINTER_FILE_PATH));
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line != null && line.length() > 0) {
                pointer = Long.valueOf(line.trim());
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            pointer = 0;
        } finally {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        }

        return pointer;
    }

}
```